# Can I change my starting character in Dead Island: Epidemic?

Tags: dead-island-epidemic

After starting *Dead Island: Epidemic*, you can choose from one of four characters with different skills/attributes.
Later in the game, I assume, you can buy those other characters with some kind of currency.

I somehow picked my usually least favourite class, the medic.

Is there a way to change the starting character, thus learning how to play with the *real* character of my choice?
If I have to reset the game to re-choose, that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't; You can have as many characters as you want/buy and later you select your favorites, so they can be selected quickly but you will be able to select any character you bought at any time.

Comment: So I have to play with my starting character until I can buy another one and there's no way to replace the first one directly?

Comment: That's correct, you just need to get more points (the icon is a hand) to buy any other character you want.

Comment: That makes your answer a "No, you can't" instead of a "Yes, you can". Edit this and I will accept it